# Running .rb file using Jenkins

Tags: ruby, windows, jenkins, scripting

I have ruby file `sample.rb`

content of file are

```
puts "Hello Ruby"
```

When I am executing this on Windows cmd it works fine but when I am trying it to execute through Jenkins it won't work.How can I run this file using Jenkins?

version of ruby I am using

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x64-mingw32]
```

**UPDATE**

Tried to run ruby -v in jenkins it gives me following error

```
[HelloRuby] $ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins8144880231444275150.bat

D:\Jenkins\workspace\HelloRuby>ruby -v 
'ruby' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\Jenkins\workspace\HelloRuby>exit 9009 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Config for ruby in jenkins
[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting, and how are you running it on jenkins? It could be many things, make sure `ruby -v` works on your jenkins, and make sure either your file is executable and with a Ruby shebang, or run it with `ruby sample.rb`.

Comment: @DannyB I have updated my question I have tried to run with ruby sample.rb it's still giving me error

Comment: can you add a  ```echo %Path%``` to make sure that the ```RUBY_HOME``` path is showing up

Comment: It's not showing up the path for `RUBY_HOME` even I have created a environment variable.